# Support for many subdomains in manifest

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

Is there a way to use dynamic subdomains for the  property in the manifest file, or something like wild cards? `<AppDomain>https://*.somedomain.com</AppDomain>` We have a large number of subdomains, 1-per customer.

Is there a good way to handle this?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, this is not supported in the manifest. (check the link in Stefan's answer). This is a feature that we know is desired, but we do not have a timeline for if/when it would be shipped.

Suggestions/Voting for this feature can be done at: https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-feature-requests-and-feedback/suggestions/13314972-support-wildcards-for-appdomains-in-office-add-in

However, wildcard subdomains on the **source URL** in the manifest are currently supported. For example, if the SourceLocation is contoso.com, then customerA.contoso.com would be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain#syntax), it's impossible.

Instead of just typing, you can generate the manifest file programmatically based on the full list of subdomains. ex; create an endpoint returns XML file (generated one with full subdomain lists.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Do you know if there is any other good solution for a changing list? We could generate the static list easily, but if we add new customers and thus new subdomains, the add-in would have to be re-submitted for approval.