# Support for wild card or RegEx to AppDomain outlook add-in manifest

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Support for a wild card to AppDomain outlook add-in manifest
Is there any way to add a wild card or RegEx to AppDomain in the outlook add-in manifest file to support all the subdomains?

```
<AppDomains>
  <AppDomain>https://*.domain.com</AppDomain>
  <AppDomain>https://{0}.domain.com</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

Comment: See this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65704844/support-for-many-subdomains-in-manifest

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify each subdomain separately.

The [rules](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/manifest/appdomain) are listed below:

- The value of the `AppDomain` element must include the protocol (e.g., https://myappdomain.com).
- If there is an explicit port for the domain, include it (e.g.,`<AppDomain>https://myappdomain.com:9999</AppDomain>`).
- If a subdomain needs to be trusted, include it (e.g.,`<AppDomain>https://mysubdomain.myappdomain.com</AppDomain>`). The subdomain `mysubdomain.mydomain.com` and `mydomain.com` are different domains. If both need to be trusted, then both need to be in separate `AppDomain` elements.
- Listing the same domain as the one specified in the `SourceLocation` element has no effect and may be misleading. In particular, when you are developing on localhost, you don't need to create an `AppDomain` element for localhost.
- Don't include any segments of a URL past the domain. For example, don't include the full URL of a page.
- Do not put a closing slash, "/", on the value.